# Converting list elements to an integer

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to retrieve the highest numerical value of all the file name within my directory and I can't seem to convert the max value list to an integer.

```
import os, glob 
import re
import math

os.chdir(os.getcwd())
numlist = []
for file in glob.glob("*.json"):
    x = re.findall("\d+",file)
    numlist.append(x)

high = max(numlist)
high_int = int(high)
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list of all matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
import os, glob 
import re

os.chdir(os.getcwd()) # this changes the current working directory to the
                      # current working directory - i.e., it does nothing
numlist = []
for file in glob.glob("*.json"):
    results = re.findall("\d+",file) # results is a list
    numlist.extend(int(elem) for elem in results)

high = max(numlist)
high_int = int(high) # not necessary, as list elements are already ints
```

[`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) adds each element from the generator expression to the end of the list, and we call `int()` on it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68884400/9997212), you can also use a list comprehension:

```py
numlist = [int(elem)
            for file in glob.glob("*.json") 
            for elem in re.findall(r"\d+", file)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the string that you get from "findall" into an integer before appending it to `numlist`.

Comment: Yes i did that, but still getting the same error "num = int(x)" before append to numlist

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.